# geozones pushwoosh in Android

Tags: android, pushwoosh

I have implemented pushwoosh in my Android app. I have not been able
to get automatic Geozone notifications.

In the Log of Eclipse I can see the LocationUpdateService that works and
update the position , in fact, if I try to manually send a notification to the devices that are located in that area , it's all ok , but automatic notifications of Geozones "that allow sending automatically triggered push notifications right at the moment a user enters the specified area on the map" don't work when I enter in a geozone.

I add this code in my activity:

```
pushManager.startTrackingGeoPushes();
```

and in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.GeoLocationService"/>
```

Has anyone tested the automatic features of geozones? Where is the problem that I do not get these notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<service android:name="com.pushwoosh.location.GeoLocationService" />
```

instead of

```
<service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.GeoLocationService"/>
```

Then in Android Monitor, when the pushManager.startTrackingGeoPushes(); is called, you will see something like:

```
[LocationUpdateService] - onLocationChanged: -31.9105168,115.8071474, accuracy: 40.5, isMoving: false, speed: 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new Android SDK, Pushwoosh said they have fixed the problems with the geo push, in particular with the service that not working when the app was not open or in background.